# override instance method in Ruby with module instead of inheritance

Tags: ruby, module, polymorphism

I'm trying to implement a method that overrides an ActiveRecord method (find) but then can also access the original find method.  I'd like to do this without inheritance, using a module.  So what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
module Override
    def find args
        if some_condition
            do_something
        else
            super args # i realize this is not a "super" but this is the functionality i seek
        end
...
```

and then in my ActiveRecord inherited class

```
include Override

... # and then business as usual
MyClass.find(id)
```

Is this possible?  The intent is to have a simple plugin that will enhance the ActiveRecord find method (with cache and other stuff), but the motivation is not my question, I want to know if Ruby supports such an idea.  The benefit of this is that I would not have to build a subclass to sit in between Rails and my class for every single class I wish to enhance with custom find behavior.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Ruby does support this, and the code you've written should already work. Did you try running it?

Comment: When you include/inherit from a module/class, ruby places it in the ancestor chain. You can see this by running: `self.class.ancestors`. Then, every time you call a method, ruby searches through the ancestor chain to find a matching definition. In this case, if you correctly include the `Override` module, it will be placed *before* `ActiveRecord::Base` in the ancestor chain - thereby taking precedence in its method definition. And calling `super` will still work exact as you've written it.

Comment: To be clear, I can't say for sure whether the the *exact* code you've written will work, because you haven't provided a complete code sample. If it doesn't work, please provide a [mcve] -- because you must only be making a small mistake.

Comment: I did try this code, and it's executing both my find and the default find.  Let me write up an example.

Comment: `MyClass.prepend(Override)` would work. Also remove all `include Override` from everywhere.

Comment: Prepend would also work, but there's no need to do that here.